# Get from <? super A>

Tags: java, generics, super

The whole idea of Generics is type-safety and preventing casts.

When i add() to a list that is `<? super A>`, the only way it lets me compile the get is to declare the variable type as Object.

```
    ArrayList<? super A> list = new ArrayList<A>();

    Object obj = list.get(0);
```

The fact is that I can only add A and A's sub-classes to this list.

***So one***, why doesnt it let me declare obj as type A?

`A obj = list.get(0);`

***And two***, the fact that type is now `Object`, it seems to loosen up the whole Generics idea - i am containing it in a umbrella type, and i need to cast the `.get()`

Comment: What is `genB`?

Comment: Is `genB` supposed to be a type? Why is it lowercase? Why are you casting to some type that doesn't seem to have anything to do with anything?

Comment: @user2357112 sorry about the typo. fixed.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the "super" is for. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Answer (score 2):

You define the list as a list of `<? super A>`, this means the list contains elements which are `A`, or any of it's superclasses, this causes a problem, because there can be any number of superclasses, which could go all the way up to `object`, so all the compiler can guarantee is that the item returned from the list is an object.

If you want to have a list that contains `A`s you should define it as a `List<A>` which guarentees the list will contain only `A`s or A's subclasses

Comment: Hi, actually, i am unable to add a superclass of A to this list. I cannot add a new Object() to it, for example. It gives me a capture #1 error. I can only add A and its subclasses to this list. So, i should be able to decalre the variable type from get as A, because it can only be of type A.

Comment: A much more in depth explanation is available here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/8041461

Comment: Hmm. It seems that using only thing i can .add() to `list` is A's subclasses, but `list` itself can point to A's superclasses. If not strange, its an Interesting finding.

Comment: @jforex78 Just because *you* cannot add `A`s to the list doesn't mean it only contains `Object`s. The *entire point* of wildcards is that the caller of code that uses it gets more freedom at the expense of the implementer's freedom (or the other way, in some cases). See: `void f(List<? super String> l) { l.add("Hello!"); } List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>(); l.add(new Object()); f(l);`

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should be "Just because you can only add subtypes of `A` to the list doesn't mean it only contains `A`s."

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable of type `List<? super A>`, you can only add values of type `A` to it *through that variable*. That doesn't mean it can't have other objects in it:

```
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(new Object());
List<? super A> l2 = l;
```

`l2.add` can only be called with values of type `A`, but `l2.get` could return non-`A` instances.